# Can't access some tabular content using xmlhttp requests

Tags: vba, post, web-scraping

I've created two scripts using vba to fetch tabular content from a [webpage](https://www.theclearinghouse.org/uid-lookup). To access the tabular content, I had to first fill in with `410611` right next to `UID#` under `Search by UID`. Then, I hit the `go` button and I got to see the tabular content.

I found success using selenium:

```
Sub FetchContent()
    Dim oInput As Object, oElem As Object

    With CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
        .get "https://www.theclearinghouse.org/uid-lookup"
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementById("uidlookup", timeout:=10000)
        Set oInput = .FindElementByCss("input[name='UidNum']", timeout:=5000)
        oInput.SendKeys "410611"
        .FindElementByCss("input#SubmitUid", timeout:=5000).Click
        Set oElem = .FindElementByCss("table#uid", timeout:=5000)
        MsgBox oElem.Text
    End With
End Sub
```

However, I wish to get the same content using xmlhttp requests. I tried like the following but unfortunately it doesn't work. The script neither throws any error nor prints anything in the immediate window. I found success using the same logic in python, though.

Using xmlhttp requests (doesn't work):

```
Sub FetchContent()
    Const URL = "https://uid.theclearinghouse.org/list.php"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "referer", "https://uid.theclearinghouse.org/index.php"
        .send ("UidNum=410611&SubmitUid=Go%21")
        Debug.Print .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

> How can I access the tabular content using xmlhttp requests?